# Directing an app to run off of a different script in AppleScript.

Tags: applescript

I'm making an applescript to help with school. You type the subject you wish to access, and then it opens that folder (inside the app). However, some subjects have ebooks, so I want there to be another dialog box asking you wether you want to open the ebook or the folder. Unfortunately, a `display dialog` can't branch off of another display dialog.

So far, the only way I've found around this is to direct the app to run off of another script (in the "Scripts" folder of the app). I've tried

```
tell application "Script Editor" to run script (path to me as sting) & "Contents:Resources:Scripts:Subject.scpt"`
```

But it didn't work. Sorry if I'm barking up the wrong tree and seem completely stupid. Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly do not need to, nor should you, accomplish this be calling an additional script. Are you saying you want two display dialogs active at the same time? Why is that? Arthur's answer below should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood what you're trying to achieve, the following script would work.

```
set listOfSubjects to {"Math", "Biology", "History", "Languages"}
set subjectsWithEbook to {"Biology", "History"}

choose from list listOfSubjects with prompt "Select the subject"
set subject to item 1 of result

set openEbook to false
repeat with subjectItem in subjectsWithEbook
    if subjectItem contains subject then
        choose from list {"Open folder", "Open Ebook"} with prompt "What to open?"
        set openType to item 1 of result

        if openType contains "Open Ebook" then
            set openEbook to true
        end if
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat


if openEbook then
    --Open ebook    
else
    --Open folder
end if
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was aiming for, yeah. I just wanted the first choose from list to be a display dialog. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to type the subject name? Here is an example that uses dialog boxes.

```
set subjectFolderPath to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:"
set subjectsWithEbook to {"English", "Spanish"}

display dialog "What subject would you like to access?" default answer ""
set theSubject to text returned of the result

if theSubject is in subjectsWithEbook then
    display dialog "Would you like to open the Folder or the Book?" buttons {"Folder", "Book"} default button 1
    set toOpen to button returned of the result
    if toOpen is "Book" then
        --  tell app "Preview" to open ???  
        beep
    else
        tell application "Finder" to open folder (subjectFolderPath & theSubject & ":")
    end if
else
    tell application "Finder" to open folder (subjectFolderPath & theSubject & ":")
end if
```

You might also want to have a list of subjects that are allowed and error check for them.